# Launch activity from FCM

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to open IncomingCallActivity when fcm notification received. I am using the bellow code,

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_incoming_call);
```

In Manifest

```
 <activity android:name=".Activities.call.IncomingCallActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="OPEN_ACTIVITY_1" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

in FirebaseMessagingService class

```
 public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    System.out.println("http fcm message::  " + remoteMessage);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), IncomingCallActivity.class);
    IncomingCall incomingCall = new IncomingCall();
    incomingCall.setJitsiToken(jsonObject.getString("jitsiToken"));
    incomingCall.setUpdatedAt(jsonObject.getString("updatedAt"));
    incomingCall.setDescription(jsonObject.getString("description"));
    incomingCall.setProfilePicture(jsonObject.getString("profilePicture"));
    incomingCall.setStatus(jsonObject.getString("status"));
    incomingCall.setUserId(jsonObject.getString("userId"));
    incomingCall.setUsername(jsonObject.getString("username"));
    incomingCall.setUrl("https://" + jsonObject.getString("url"));
    incomingCall.setType(jsonObject.getString("type"));
    incomingCall.setGroup(jsonObject.getString("group"));
    incomingCall.setVideo(jsonObject.getString("video"));
    incomingCall.setCreatedAt(jsonObject.getString("createdAt"));
    incomingCall.setFullName(jsonObject.getString("fullName"));
    incomingCall.setUnreadNotification(jsonObject.getString("unreadNotification"));
    incomingCall.setUnreadNotification(jsonObject.getString("unreadNotification"));
    incomingCall.setNotificationType(jsonObject.getString("notificationType"));
    incomingCall.setCallRoomId(jsonObject.getString("callRoomId"));
    intent.putExtra("data", new Gson().toJson(incomingCall));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

}

But this is not working in android 11 when application is in background or not opened.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's expected behavior for Android 10 and higher.
From the documentation:

> Android 10 (API level 29) and higher place restrictions on when apps
> can start activities when the app is running in the background. By the
> guideline you should display notification(to provide urgent
> information) instead.

But, anyway it has a list of exceptions when you can start activity from the background. You can find the list here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts#exceptions

Maybe some exceptions from the list will work for your case.

Comment: I have tried but nothing is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + this.getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        } else {
            //Permission Granted-System will work
        }
    }
```